# Download the last version of a file

Tags: github

I just wanted to verify the changes made to the file and this view is great.

https://github.com/shantanuo/marathi_spell_check/commit/410a68e5e29367e4208c9492ff5952eb6c7b50ff?diff=split

But how do I download the last version shown on the left? I do not want to revert back, I just need that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the commit hash then use it to view the file at that point in the tree:

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shantanuo/marathi_spell_check/410a68e5e29367e4208c9492ff5952eb6c7b50ff/dicts/mr_IN.aff`

Prev commit is: 8cf176b74de39f5acfb363d9d8647635683cc70d, which can be found in the [file history](https://github.com/shantanuo/marathi_spell_check/commits/master/dicts/mr_IN.aff).

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I got that file. Isn't there easier way to view the earlier version?

Comment: Yeah as said you use the hash of the commit to reference it, and use github or the cli to find out the hash of a previous commit, what do you mean by easier?